# How can I make my \n a new Line in HTML

Tags: java, html, string, newline

Basically I have a string with \n and I want to display on a editable textbox in html. My problem is that in HTML i get everything in a new line and it's a big mess.

How can I replace the `\n` with `<br>` or something like that  to make new lines in html??

JAVA `GitLab.getProjectFile()` Return this string (it's not this but it's the same format):

```
blablabla\nblablabla\nbla bla bla\n
```

In HTML I'm calling like this:

```
<div style="margin-top:20px;">
   <%
        String data = GitLab.getProjectFile();
    %>
    <%=data%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just call `replace`:

```
String data = GitLab.getProjectFile().replace("\n", "<br/>");
```

Comment: As a side note: since Java 8 to represent in regex different line separators like `\r\n` sequence or `\r` we can use `\R` like `replaceAll("\\R","<br/>")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem without having to replace any newlines by using CSS. Just add `white-space: pre-line;` to the style attribute as follows:

```
<div style="margin-top:20px; white-space: pre-line;">
    <%
        String data = GitLab.getProjectFile();
    %>
    <%=data%>
</div>
```

One of the advantages of this approach is that you won't have to strip `<br/>` tags from the text you retrieve in the textbox.

There are other CSS whitespace options if `pre-line` isn't quite what you're looking for. You can see a description of them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).